# Powershell keyboard-filter for specific user

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell

This page from Microsoft : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/keyboardfilter-add-blocked-key-combinations explains how to create a powershell script that will disable specific key combinations.

Here is the relevant code snippets...

```
function Enable-Custom-Key($Id) {
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Toggle on a Custom Key keyboard filter Rule
    .Description
        Use Get-WMIObject to enumerate all WEKF_CustomKey instances,
        filter against key value "Id", and set that instance's "Enabled"
        property to 1/true.

        In the case that the Custom instance does not exist, add a new
        instance of WEKF_CustomKey using Set-WMIInstance.
    .Example
        Enable-Custom-Key "Ctrl+V"
        Enable filtering of the Ctrl + V sequence.
#>

    $custom = Get-WMIObject -class WEKF_CustomKey @CommonParams |
        where {
            $_.Id -eq "$Id"
        };

    if ($custom) {
# Rule exists.  Just enable it.
        $custom.Enabled = 1;
        $custom.Put() | Out-Null;
        "Enabled Custom Filter $Id.";

    } else {
        Set-WMIInstance `
            -class WEKF_CustomKey `
            -argument @{Id="$Id"} `
            @CommonParams | Out-Null
        "Added Custom Filter $Id.";
    }
}


Enable-Custom-Key "Windows+U"
# etc.
```

However, is there a way that will disable the key combinations, but only for a specific user? (i.e. I want another "administrator" user on the same computer that can continue use the key combinations)

I thought maybe logging in as that user and running the script would do it, but for one thing it only seems to work if I run Powershell as an administrator, and then when I do, I log back out and back in as the other, "administrator" user and the key combinations are blocked here too.

It's Windows 10 IoT.

(BTW I'm open to answers which don't use Powershell at all. I had previously been told to use the Group Policy Editor, but I couldn't find the Keyboard Filter section)

Comment: Messing with hardware is a global/machine level thing, thus Windows security boundaries require one to be an admin for global/machine level config, just like it is for installing apps, unless you give a user admin privs needed (using GPO or LP) to do X or Y, without making them full admin.

Comment: @postanote - I don't mind performing the actions as admin, that I understand. My question is how to limit the key combinations for a specific user. e.g. so one user would be able to close a Window with Alt+F4 but another user would not.

Answer (score 0):

Try DisableKeyboardFilterForAdministrators

Comment: That doesn't fix for a specific user, just for any administrator accounts on the computer.